# Read files in mocha tests asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, global-variables, es6-promise

I'm not getting the value of Input and Output variables. I have tried using this keyword also in the below code.

```js
it("Final Decoding Tests", () => {
  let input = "";
  let output = "";

  fs.readFile("./test/test_data/booksEncoded.txt", { encoding: "utf-8" }, (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      this.input = data;
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  fs.readFile("./test/test_data/books.xml", { encoding: "utf-8" }, (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      this.output = data;
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  console.log(input); // NO OUTPUT
  console.log(this.output); //PRINTS undefined
});
```

I think I have to read the files asynchronously using the `done` callback.

My question is:

Why I'm not getting any values for the input and output outside the fs.readFile methods? and Is there any way to read it using **done** keyword asynchronously?

Comment: You could use the done callback but in this case I think it would be easier for you to use `let input = readFileSync(..)` to get rid of the async behaviour.

Comment: Alternatively you could look into `async/await` which also works out of the box using mocha.

Comment: Yeah it worked using async await. Thanks..!

Comment: Glad to hear it :) you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `util.promisify(original)` method to get a promise version of `fs.readFile`.

E.g.

`index.spec.js`:

```js
const util = require("util");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const { expect } = require("chai");

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

describe("57841192", () => {
  it("Final Decoding Tests", async () => {
    const basepath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./test/test_data");
    const options = { encoding: "utf-8" };
    const readInput = readFile(path.join(basepath, "booksEncoded.txt"), options);
    const readOutput = readFile(path.join(basepath, "books.xml"), options);
    const [input, output] = await Promise.all([readInput, readOutput]);
    expect(input).to.be.equal("haha");
    expect(output).to.be.equal("<item>unit test</item>");
    console.log(input);
    console.log(output);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
  57841192
haha
<item>unit test</item>
    ✓ Final Decoding Tests


  1 passing (9ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57841192

Comment: Thank You so much..! It helped